Failed to load config "plugin:@ts-safeql/eslint-plugin" to extend from
I am using nx 19 and nx/nest. I also use flat eslint config. All my nx commands currently return

Please assist. I can not even run nx report. It fails
I have tried multiple instructions but all instructions with verbose turned on all my eslint files are failing with

